# Lagrange Error Bound for $\ln(x)$ yields an error too large

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Consider the problem of finding the maximum possible error of the 3rd-degree Taylor Series (centered at $x = 1$) of $y = \ln{x}$ on the domain $[0.3, 1.7]$.

My idea was to use the Lagrange Error Bound, which states that the maximum possible error is

\begin{equation*}
\dfrac{M}{(n + 1)!}|x - a|^{n + 1}
\end{equation*}
where

- $n$ is the degree of the Taylor polynomial being used ($3$ here); and
- M is the maximum magnitude of the $n + 1$th (the 4th) derivative of $f$ on the domain (where $f$ is the aforementioned function $y = \ln{x}$); and
- $a$ is the center of the Taylor approximation.

I computed the fourth derivative of $f$ as $-6x^{-4}$. This has a maximum magnitude when $x = 0.3$, which yields $M = \dfrac{-6}{0.3^4}$. Then, because our Taylor Series is centered at $x = 1$, the maximum possible value of $|x - a|$ is $0.7$. Finally, $n = 3$. Plugging this in, I had that the maximum error was

\begin{equation*}
\left| \dfrac{\dfrac{-6}{0.3^4}}{4!} 0.7^4 \right| \approx 7.41
\end{equation*}

But the actual answer is 0.1446, which I have verified from the actual graphs. **Can someone spot if I am making a mistake here?**

Comment: There is no reason in general that the actual error is related to the max error, other than being smaller than the max error.

Comment: The Lagrange error bound gives an *upper bound* for the maximum error. It does not tell you the actual value of the maximum error. It is certainly true that $0.1446 \le 7.41$.

Comment: Ah, I see. It makes sense, then, why it's called the error *bound* - because that's all it is, a upper bound on the absolute error. But now, in this case, how can I rigorously go about the problem? It intuitively makes sense to me that the maximum errors are at the endpoints of the domain (because here, those are the points furthest away from the center of the Taylor Series expansion), but is there a way to mathematically prove the maximum error between this Taylor Series polynomial and $y = \ln{x}$ on this domain?

Comment: In general, if you want the exact maximum error, you have to explicitly calculate it from your function.

Comment: Extra for this case the Schlömilch formula for the residual error was invented. Generally, take the integral formula and extract a different weight factor.